# Keybindings in react

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've been trying to figure out keybindings in React and I'm a bit stuck.

I placed a onKeyPress and also tried a onKeyDown on my input. This allowed me to handle all letters and the Enter key.

However I haven't been able to find a good way to handle the arrow keys and the Esc key without just creating a document.addEventListener('keydown'', this.onKeypress)

Anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Is there a particular problem with attaching the event listener to `document` or `window`?

Comment: Well I prefer my events to not be firing constantly. If it is attached just to the input then it only fires when I have it focused. It is a search bar that is visible on all pages which means that events would be firing a lot on every page.

Comment: Events fire the whole way up the DOM regardless of where you add the event listener. The only way to stop them is with `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault`.

Comment: I usually do that. Are you saying it propagates all the way up even on reacts onKeyPress. There is a third flag that you can add to the document eventListener to change this behavior I thought but yeah I usually prevent default.

Comment: Actually, React uses event delegation to avoid adding DOM listeners on every node when you use `onClick`, etc.

Comment: That's not what event delegation is. The browser captures and bubbles down and up through the DOM whenever they happen (regardless of whether there are handlers or not). Event delegation is just a side effect of the fact that events bubble up the DOM.

Comment: @DanPrince I think Aaron's short definition is exactly what event delegation is. It's a technique, not a side-effect. https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `focus` and `blur` events to control the lifecycle of your event handler.

```
render() {
  return (
    <input ref={inputLoaded} type="text" />
  );
},
inputLoaded(input) {
  input.addEventListener('focus', this.addEventListeners);
  input.addEventListener('blur', this.removeEventListeners);
  this.input = input;
},
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.input.removeEventListener('focus', this.addEventListeners);
  this.input.removeEventListener('blur', this.removeEventListeners);
  window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKey);
},
addEventListeners() {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKey);
},
removeEventListeners() {
  window.removeEventListeners('keydown', this.handleKey);
},
handleKey(event) {
  // this only gets called if input is focused.
  // do something with this key
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the `focus` and `blur` events to control a `state` variable, then check whether the input has focus inside the `handleKey` method, before doing some work.

Comment: @doublecheeseburger If this answer helped you, could you consider marking it as the accepted answer?